# If a value does not exist go to the next spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to search for certain values in `Excel spreadsheets`. However sometimes an element might not be in the `spreadsheet`.

For example if i am searching for Raw Copper Reserves i might have it in `sheets 1` and `2` but not `3`.

So i have written this code:

```
q = 1
    Case 2
    find_Element = fin_Array(x)

        For k = 3 To last_WS
            With Sheets(k).Range("1:200")
                sh_Name = Worksheets(k).Name
                Set pointer_to_Element = .Find(find_Element, _
                    .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, _
                    xlNext, False)
                If pointer_to_Element Is Nothing Or "" Then
                    find_Element = "Finished goods"
                End If
                Set pointer_to_Element = .Find(find_Element, _
                    .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, _
                    xlNext, False)
                pointer_Int_Row = CInt(pointer_to_Element.Row)

                Worksheets(k).Cells(pointer_Int_Row, lock_Array(k)).Copy
                Worksheets("EXTRACTIONS").Range("B16").Offset(, q).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Worksheets("EXTRACTIONS").Range("B15").Offset(, q).Value = sh_Name
                q = q + 1
            End With
```

---

*Question_1*: Why is it always throwing an `error` on line:

```
If pointer_to_Element is Nothing or "" then
```

*Question_2*: I have replaced in `Find` the `xlWhole` with `xlPart` but how do i work this when the element is missing from this `sheet`?

How can i make it to just walk to the next `sheet`?

|
How can i check in `VBAish` if the value "Land and land improvements" does not exist in the `Sheet` and go to the next `Sheet`? (preferably without using the `GoTo`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
If pointer_to_Element Is Nothing Or "" Then
```

would be more syntactically correct as

```
If pointer_to_Element Is Nothing Or pointer_to_Element = "" Then
```

but the `Range.Find` method returns **Nothing** if nothing is found, so you only need the first check:

```
If pointer_to_Element Is Nothing Then
```

For the second part of your question you could put all the remaining code in an **Else** block. That is, it will only execute the code in the Else if it finds something. Otherwise, it will continue to the next sheet.

Comment: Thanks @AndyG Although i will test tommorow! I definitelly kicked the bucket today!